# Best way to post FQL result to cakephp controller with jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, cakephp, facebook-fql

I have an fql result that's a javascript object that looks like this:

```
[{"name":"3904","fql_result_set":[{"like_count":"0"}]},{"name":"7617","fql_result_set":[{"like_count":"0"}]},{"name":"9674","fql_result_set":[{"like_count":"0"}]}]
```

I can't find a a way to pass it to my controller so as to be able to access the data from my controller and echo back to me as a simple test.

I can send simple json strings like `{"name":john","id":2323}` to the controller and have it send it back by using `$this->params[form]['name'] & $this->params['form']['id]` in the controller, but I'm not sure how to format the FQL result to send it to my cake controller via ajax and retrieve it using cakephp.  Do I need to stringify it or should I make iterate through and create a json simpler json string?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by adding a name to the entire json object so that when it get's posted
to the controller, it could be accessed using the name/value convention.  In this case, the name is data and the value is the array. Without adding the name to the object, the data  in the object would not get to the controller intact.

```
{"data":[{"name":"3904","fql_result_set":[{"like_count":"0"}]},{"name":"7617","fql_result_set":[{"like_count":"0"}]},{"name":"9674","fql_result_set":[{"like_count":"0"}]}]}
```

So it can now be accessed like so: `$this->data[0]['name']`, or `$this->data[0]['fql_resut_set'][0]['like_count']`.